# What is @javax.ws.rs.core.Context

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

First of all, I am very new to this topic and not sure if its a very basic question. I couldnt help but posting here.

I am looking at a code that uses restful webservice. An ajax call is being made inorder to provide details to this ws. The method signature looks like this:

```
@Path("/issues")
@GET
public Response getIssueCockpit(@javax.ws.rs.core.Context HttpServletRequest paramHttpServletRequest, @QueryParam("filterGlobal") String paramString) throws Exception 
{ 
    //Code here
}
```

I understand that the webservice caller calls this API using "eg: http://app/resource/issues1" and this method gets called.

1. Can you please help me understand what is `@javax.ws.rs.core.Context HttpServletRequest paramHttpServletRequest` in the below method call.
2. What does the annotation do in this case.
3. An ajax call is being made to provide details to this WS> How is the context preserved in the ServletRequest.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5):

The `HttpServletRequest` object represents the HTTP request from the browser or client application. So a call to "`http://app/resource/issues1`" is represented by an instance of the `HttpServletRequest`. This object has methods that report information about the request such as the Http headers, Media type, and the request body.

[The annotation `@Context`](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/what-is-javax-ws-rs-core-context-httpheaders-and-uriinfo/) injects (just like `@Autowired` from Spring and `@Inject` from Java EE) the `HttpServletRequest` instance for the request made to the path (`/issue`) with HTTP method type (`GET`). In fact, the `@Context` annotation can inject a vast number of very useful objects related to the request. See the full list below:

- [HttpHeaders](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/what-is-javax-ws-rs-core-context-httpheaders-and-uriinfo/) -> HTTP header parameters and values
- [UriInfo](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/what-is-javax-ws-rs-core-context-httpheaders-and-uriinfo/) -> Captures path variables and query parameters
- [SecurityContext](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/what-is-javax-ws-rs-core-context-securitycontext/) -> Provides access to security-related information for a request
- [ResourceContext](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/what-is-javax-ws-rs-core-context-securitycontext/) -> Provides access to instances of resource classes
- [Request](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/what-is-javax-ws-rs-core-context-request-and-configuration-providers-and-application/) -> Precondition request processing
- [Application](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/what-is-javax-ws-rs-core-context-request-and-configuration-providers-and-application/), [Configuration](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/what-is-javax-ws-rs-core-context-request-and-configuration-providers-and-application/), and [Providers](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/what-is-javax-ws-rs-core-context-request-and-configuration-providers-and-application/) -> Provide information about the JAX-RS application environment
- [HttpServletRequest](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/what-is-javax-ws-rs-core-context-httpservletresponse-and-httpservletrequest/) -> Provides access to the HttpServletRequest instance
- [HttpServletResponse](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/what-is-javax-ws-rs-core-context-httpservletresponse-and-httpservletrequest/) -> Provides access to the HttpServletResponse instance
- [ServletConfig](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/what-is-javax-ws-rs-core-context-servletconfig-and-servletcontext/) -> Provides access to the ServletConfig
- [ServletContext](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/what-is-javax-ws-rs-core-context-servletconfig-and-servletcontext/) -> Provides access to the ServletContext

The `ServletRequest` lives for as long as the request exists. This is normally very short-lived so for the duration of the request the `ServletRequest` is maintaining.

Answer (score 3):

If you've worked with an dependency injection frameworks like Spring or CDI, you'll see that in order to let the framework inject a dependency, you need a marker annotation. In Spring you would see `@Autowired` or `@Inject`, in CDI you would see `@Inject`. `@Context` works the same way. In order for the JAX-RS runtime to know that `HttpServletRequest` is to be injected, it needs to be annotated with `@Context`. Same way JAX-RS knows to inject the query parameter is through the `@QueryParam` annotation.

The `HttpServletRequest` is from the servlet container. When a request comes the container creates the `HttpServletRequest` and passes it down to servlet implementations. The JAX-RS runtime hands this object to your resource method/class, if it sees that you want it, by annotating it.